# Optimizing ajax speed for use in a gameserver (MMO)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a browser-based game (MMO) with a server and client, all using PHP, jQuery and simple ajax calls. For the server I use a PHP daemon. The server and client need to communicate with each other as fast as possible. Right now I'm reaching responses times of about 500 ms (server is in US, I'm in Europe) which I am quite happy with, even with multiple players online! You can try it out yourself here: http://www.nickotopia.com/

Would it be possible to increase this speed even further using technologies I don't know of? I heard it would be a smart move to transfer to Node.js as they can handle even faster ajax calls. Would it be worth it, considering in my case the distance between the server and client?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the 500ms is referring to your ping, there is no way to improve that except by using a server closer to your location.  If you want to talk about optimizing your scripts, we'd need to see execution time of the script and not latency.

Comment: He wrote response times, that includes both RTT to the server and execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of repeating Ajax calls (as I guess you are doing), you should use a server-push solution, [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)-like, to reduce the number of useless communications between server and browser.

Answer (score 0):

There's an jquery plugin called ape, http://www.ape-project.org that might fit your needs, it's using the same principiel as comet.

Marten